# how to make gradle refresh part dependencies of jar

Tags: gradle

Some jar update frequently,so I can using this to refresh dependencies:

```
./gradlew build -x test --refresh-dependencies
```

but the problem is refresh is very slow,so I want to only refresh 1 or 2 jars.What should I do to make it refresh and aways using the latest jar,this is what I am tried:

```
api("com.sportswin.soa:soa-misc-biz:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"){
            changing = true
        }
```

But aways download the old one,it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `changing = true` is not needed, this is already the case for a `-SNAPSHOT` dependency.

What you are looking for is [changing the refresh time for changing dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sec:controlling_dependency_caching_programmatically), as the default is 24 hours.

This can be done as follows:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 4, 'hours'
}
```

Adapt the period to what's needed for your build.
This will only apply to changing dependencies, like snapshots, but not cause a refresh of other dependencies. So the performance impact should be minimal ... unless you mostly depend on snapshots.

Comment: you save my time.